# Error in installing htk tool kit

Tags: ubuntu, installation, htk

I am trying to install HTK tool kit in ubuntu 64 bit.In the make all step I am getting the following error.I am not able to find a solution for it.Could you please help me with this.I searched in google and try the solutions.still its not working.Please help.

```
make all
(cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \
  || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
 make[1]: Entering directory `/home/taps/Downloads/htk/HTKLib'
 gcc  -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="i686"' -Wall -Wno-    switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o HGraf.o HGraf.c
HGraf.c:73:77: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
#include <X11/Xlib.h>      /* the X11 stuff makes string.h also    available *
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731232/make-error-when-building-htk-with-cygwin?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

run

```
./configure --disable-hslab
```

before `make`. This is only tool with GUI in HTK for editing label files, you won't need it as there are many tools on the Internet for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably install libx11-dev with:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```