# Building HTK without X11

Tags: makefile, cygwin, htk

I am trying to install HTK using Cygwin (32 bit) on a x86_64 computer build.  This is part of the error I get when running

> ./configure
>
> make all

gcc = 5.4.0, g++ = 5.4.0, perl = 5; I have X11 folder in C:/cygwin/usr/share

Let me know if I should post the entire error of the make file.

HSLab.c: In function ‘FileExists’:
HSLab.c:1209:12: warning: variable ‘isEXF’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    Boolean isEXF;               /* File name is extended */
            ^
/tmp/ccZO1TK3.o: In function `InitBar':
/cygdrive/c/users/stevenha29/My Documents/htk/HTKTools/HSLab.c:344: undefined reference to`HTextWidth'
/cygdrive/c/users/stevenha29/My Documents/htk/HTKTools/HSLab.c:348: undefined reference to `HSetColour'
/cygdrive/c/users/stevenha29/My Documents/htk/HTKTools/HSLab.c:349: undefined reference to`HTextHeight'
/cygdrive/c/users/stevenha29/My Documents/htk/HTKTools/HSLab.c:349: undefined reference to `HPrintf'
/cygdrive/c/users/stevenha29/My Documents/htk/HTKTools/HSLab.c:350: undefined reference to`HSetGrey'
/cygdrive/c/users/stevenha29/My Documents/htk/HTKTools/HSLab.c:351: undefined reference to `HFillRectangle'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
./configure --without-x --disable-hslab
```

to disable Xlib and HSLab

Overall, Cygwin is a bad idea, it is better to use Linux, you can install it in Virtualbox.

Comment: doing this command did not work for me but I'll look into Virtualbox for now. Thanks!

Comment: To build the stable release 3.4.1 of HTK, I used Linux-2.6 32 Bit version on VirtualBox because there were problems when I tried building it with the 64 bit OS and now its finally working! Thanks Nikolay!