# Install HTK on Mac Error X11/Xos.h not found

Tags: htk

I need to install HTK for my project related to sound processing. But when I installed it, I got an error like this:

```
gcc  -m64 -ansi -std=gnu99 -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="x86_64"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o HGraf.o HGraf.c
HGraf.c:88:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xos.h' file not found
#include <X11/Xos.h>
```

It seems that Xcode doesn't have `Xos.h`. I have also checked in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers/X11` and can't find `Xos.h`.

I have installed Xcode version 2354 and also install XQuartz, but I still get this error. 
My HTK version is 3.5 (the newest one).

Does anyone here know how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make error when building HTK with Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731232/make-error-when-building-htk-with-cygwin)

Comment: Simply disable X in configure, it is not necessary

Comment: I think HTK 3.5 doesn't have configure script. I have downloaded it and I don't found configure.sh in the folder

Btw Im running this code
➜ make -f MakefileCPU all && make -f MakefileCPU install
in HTKTools folder

Comment: Then you have to edit makefiles.